# Ant "Java" Task not running

Tags: java, ant

So I have this ant file and it works up until it gets to the "run" task. It cleans and compiles, but when it gets to "run", nothing happens. I don't even get an error message.
I know that it isn't a problem with the program it's running, since it runs fine when i do java Driver on the command line.

```
<project name="lab3" default="run">

  <target name="run" depends="compile">
      <java classname="Driver" fork="true"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="clean">
     <javac srcdir="." includes="**/*.java" includeantruntime="false"/>
  </target> 

  <target name="clean">
    <delete>
       <fileset dir="." includes="**/*.class, **/*.jar"/>
    </delete>
  </target> 

</project>
```

a big thank you to anyone who will help a beginner out!

Comment: You should specify more parameters such as the classpath. If you need more details in the output, I guess you can run ant in verbose mode with the "-v" option.

Comment: thank you, the problem is in the classpath

Comment: Specify the failonerror=true parameter and then the build fail when the spawned JVM returns with a non-zero exist code

Answer (score 2):

Try removing fork="true" from the <java> task. It is currently spawning a separate JVM.